# R - failed installation of package with github dependency

Tags: r, github, cran, r-package, drat

I want to install a package that has a dependency from github. In the `DESCRIPTION` file of the package it says

```
Imports: ggplot2, ggthemr
Remotes: cttobin/ggthemr@0b2e7da43d4d2844b08b039510b31078
```

However, when I try to install the package, automatic installation of the `ggthemr` package from github as a dependency fails without any informative error message. It looks like as if it tried to install the dependency from CRAN instead of github.

In the `PACKAGES` file of the repository where I want to install the package from (a `drat` repo), the Imports are listed, the Remotes are not. Adding the Remotes line manually does not solve the problem.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the command you use for installation?

Comment: `install.packages`

Comment: Try devtools::install_github() instead...https://github.com/hadley/devtools

Comment: updated: I want to install `ggthemr` in an automated way as a dependency of the package I am trying to install.

Comment: I recommend using a repository.  I like [drat](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/drat) for that and I use it extensively at work and other (open source) places.  (Disclaimer: I also wrote drat.)

Comment: I am actually using `drat`, which is great! Still I face this issue.

Comment: Well if you use drat, then why don't you just place all elements of the dependency chain into the drat repo?  Then `install.packages()` will work.  Been there, done that with a few things before they hit CRAN.

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely try it. Could you please tell me then what is the role of the Remotes field and how it can and should be used?